# Identation problem while switch to jupyter notebook

Tags: python

Have tried using the commands and changing the space and tabs but still, the error continues appearing

```
 1 import osmium
 2 import shapely.wkb as wkblib
 3 class StreetsHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
 4     def __init__(self):
 5         osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
 6         self.num_nodes = 0
 7         self.num_relations = 0
 8         self.num_ways = 0
 9         self.street_relations = []
10         self.street_relation_members = []
11         self.street_ways = []
12         # A global factory that creates WKB from a osmium geometry
13         self.wkbfab = osmium.geom.WKBFactory()
14 def way(self, w):
15         if w.tags.get("highway") is not None and w.tags.get("name") is no
16             try:
17                 wkb = self.wkbfab.create_linestring(w)
18                 geo = wkblib.loads(wkb, hex=True)
19             except:
20                 return
21 row = { "w_id": w.id, "geo": geo }
22            
23             for key, value in w.tags:
24                 row[key] = value
25                 
26             self.street_ways.append(row)
27             self.num_ways += 1 
28         
29     def relation(self, r):
30         if r.tags.get("type") == "associatedStreet" and r.tags.get("name"
31             row = { "r_id": r.id }
32             for key, value in r.tags:
33                 row[key] = value
34             self.street_relations.append(row)
35             
36             for member in r.members:
37                 self.street_relation_members.append({ 
38                     "r_id": r.id, 
39                     "ref": member.ref, 
40                     "role": member.role, 
41                     "type": member.type, })
42 self.num_relations += 1
```

This is what I get

```
  File "<tokenize>", line 29
    def relation(self, r):
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: `def way` is not part of the class as it probably supposed to be because of the `self` parameter. Try indenting it.

Comment: Make sure you have the exact same indentation here as in your original code. Stackoverflow's markdown editor might mess things up, since both markdown and python syntax uses significant whitespace.

Comment: line 13, starting with `def way` and line 20 starting with `row =`, and line 41 starting with `self.num_relations` seem to have wonky indentation. But that does not explain the IndentationError from line 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `way` inside the class definition is not indented properly. Please indent it and it will solve the problem.